# recording audio in android with media recorder

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder, voice-recording

I used media recorder class to recording voice and upload it to webserver but i don't know when the file of recording voice is written completely on SD card.

Do you know an interface that can help me to find out whether the file is saved complete on SD card or not.

Answer (score 1):

are you not stopping the recording yourself?? Well here is what I would do if I were in a scenario like that of yours.

1. Create a `MediaRecorder` object and set the following attributes:

   ```
   private MediaRecorder myAudioRecorder; 
   String outputFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/recording.3gp";
   myAudioRecorder=new MediaRecorder();
   myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
   myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
   myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
   myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(outputFile);
   ```
2. Start the recording by calling these methods on click of a record button:

   ```
   record.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           try {
               myAudioRecorder.prepare();
               myAudioRecorder.start();
           } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Recording started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   });
   ```
3. Stop the recording on click of a stop button and then upload the file:

   ```
   stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           myAudioRecorder.stop();
           myAudioRecorder.release();
           myAudioRecorder  = null;

           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Audio recorded successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           doUpload(outputFile); //call the method to upload your file and perform upload.
       }
   });
   ```

As soon as you stop the mediaRecorder and release it, the recorded file is done saving in your memory card so you don't have to worry about it. Just upload you file right after that.

Comment: thanks for answer, but the problem is media recorder class save file in background and i need to know when the writting on SD card complete.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below code for voice record

```
public class AudioRecorder {

    private boolean singleFile = true;

    public MediaRecorder recorder;

    private ArrayList<String> files = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String fileDirectory;

    private String finalAudioPath;

    private boolean isRecording;

    public boolean isStarted;

    public boolean isRecording() {
        return isRecording;
    }

    public String getAudioFilePath() {
        return finalAudioPath;
    }

    public AudioRecorder(String audioFileDirectory) {
        this.fileDirectory = audioFileDirectory;

        if (!this.fileDirectory.endsWith("/")) {
            this.fileDirectory += "/";
        }

        newRecorder();
    }

    public boolean start() {
        prepareRecorder();

        try {
            recorder.prepare();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

        if (recorder != null) {
            recorder.start();
            isRecording = true;
            isStarted = true;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public boolean pause() {
        if (recorder == null || !isRecording) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("[AudioRecorder] recorder is not recording!");
        }

        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;

        isRecording = false;

        return merge();
    }

    public boolean resume() {
        if (isRecording) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("[AudioRecorder] recorder is recording!");
        }

        singleFile = false;
        newRecorder();
        return start();
    }

    public boolean stop() {
        if (!isRecording) {
            return merge();
        }

        if (recorder == null) {
            return false;
        }

        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        recorder = null;
        isRecording = false;
        isStarted = false;
        return merge();
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (recorder != null || isRecording) {
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            recorder = null;
            isRecording = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0, len = files.size(); i < len; i++) {
            File file = new File(this.files.get(i));
            file.delete();
        }
        finalAudioPath = "";
    }

    private boolean merge() {

        // If never paused, just return the file
        if (singleFile) {
            this.finalAudioPath = this.files.get(0);
            return true;
        }

        // Merge files
        String mergedFilePath = this.fileDirectory + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".amr";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(mergedFilePath);

            for (int i = 0, len = files.size(); i < len; i++) {

                try {
                    File file = new File(this.files.get(i));
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

                    // Skip file header bytes,
                    // amr file header's length is 6 bytes
                    if (i > 0) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                            fis.read();
                        }
                    }

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
                    int count = 0;
                    while ((count = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        fos.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }

                    fis.close();
//                    fos.flush();
//                    file.delete();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
//            files.clear();
            this.finalAudioPath = mergedFilePath;
//            files.add(this.finalAudioPath)
            return true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void newRecorder() {
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    }

    private void prepareRecorder() {
        File directory = new File(this.fileDirectory);
        if (!directory.exists() || !directory.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("[AudioRecorder] audioFileDirectory is a not valid directory!");
        }

        String filePath = directory.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".amr";
        this.files.add(filePath);

        recorder.setOutputFile(filePath);
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    }
}
```